# why we need data labelling tool for computer vision?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, labels

Before start training images with tensorflow object detection api we need to use labelling tool to annotate our images and converted to XML format.
What happens when we convert our annoted image to XML file? Why we need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to label data in order to train classifier. Labelled data are at the basis of all supervised ML. XML files are just one of the many format you can use to store information, people usually use them since they can be easily read by many tools.